# Need to make a button create a record and attach a file

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

It's my first post here and I love how helpful people are on this site!

I have very little experience with vba in general so bear with me. And before you ask, I have spent a lot of time searching for my answer on this site as well as msdn with no luck.

I am designing a database for my work to keep track of employees and their contact info, training courses, and hiring documentation. I have hit a small road block with the hiring forms.

I have a form with employee's information and a subform that has a list of all their documentation. Each document is a record on a separate "documents" table that is pulled up with a query. The table has a field for the employee name, the type of document (resume et cetera) and the attachment itself. I have a dropdown box that has a list of document types. When I select an option from the combo box I would like it to create a new record in the "documents" table using the employee name from the current employee being shown, the document type selected from the combo box, then open the choose file dialogue.

[Here is what I have so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFJeU.png)

I have read microsoft's article on adding attachments which was helpful but doesn't tell me how to create a new record on another table.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Attach-files-and-graphics-to-the-records-in-your-database-bced3638-bfbc-43f0-822d-374bca2e6b40?CorrelationId=5332de93-8a42-4f76-bb47-c196bc1ce75b&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Update: I've come a long way with the code, but i am getting stuck with inserting the attachment

```
Sub test()
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset2
Dim rsA As DAO.Recordset2
Dim fld As DAO.Field2

'variables for file path
Dim sName
Dim f As Object
Dim strFile As String
Dim strFolder As String
Dim varItem As Variant

Set dbs = CurrentDb
Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("documents")
Set fld = rst("doc")
Set rsA = fld.Value
rst.AddNew
rst!inspector = "test"
rst.Update

    Set f = Application.FileDialog(3)
        f.AllowMultiSelect = True
        If f.Show Then
            For Each varItem In f.SelectedItems
                strFile = Dir(varItem)
                strFolder = Left(varItem, Len(varItem) - Len(strFile))
                'MsgBox "Folder: " & strFolder & vbCrLf & _
                    "File: " & strFile
            Next
        End If
        Set f = Nothing
        sName = strFolder & strFile
rst.Edit
rst.AddNew
rsA("FileData").LoadFromFile sName  ' <<<this is where i get stuck
rsA.Update
rst.Update

MsgBox ("done") 'test
```

End Sub

Comment: You need to run an Insert query and have it fired by the Combo box change event. It would be safer to have it attached to a button, that way mistakenly selecting the wrong document wouldn't create spurious records. You'd then want to refresh your form query source. All in all, probably about 6 lines of VBA. Have a go, and let us know if you have problems.

Comment: Thanks Gavin. I already know to use the change event but it is the vba code that i am having trouble with. since I do not have enough reputation on SO i cant post my code in a new comment. Please see my edits to the original post. Maybe you can spot where my problem is.

Answer (score 0):

After banging my head against the desk for 2 days i finally have the code. I still need to make adjustments to fill in the other fields with the inspector name and the type of file, but it should be easy sailing from here. I was having the most trouble with creating a record and attaching a file

```
Sub test()

Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim tbl As DAO.Recordset2
Dim field As DAO.Recordset2

'variables for file path
Dim sName
Dim f As Object
Dim strFile As String
Dim strFolder As String
Dim varItem As Variant

Set db = CurrentDb
Set tbl = db.OpenRecordset("documents")

    'get file path string
    Set f = Application.FileDialog(3)
        f.AllowMultiSelect = False
        If f.Show Then
            For Each varItem In f.SelectedItems
                strFile = Dir(varItem)
                strFolder = Left(varItem, Len(varItem) - Len(strFile))
            Next
        End If
        Set f = Nothing
        sName = strFolder & strFile

    tbl.Edit
    tbl.AddNew 'add a new entry to the table
    tbl!inspector = "test"

    Set field = tbl.Fields("doc").Value
    field.AddNew 'add an attachment to the record
    field.Fields("FileData").LoadFromFile sName
    field.Update
    tbl.Update




End Sub
```